# How to share folder over user id based wi-fi network?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I am working in a shared office, where i get one user id and password for connecting 2 laptops. I want to share folder or drive between these 2 laptop. If i use mobile hot spot then i am able to share folder. If i use shared office wifi then another laptop folder is not visible in first laptop. (In shared wifi first i connect wifi network by a password after then a page open in browser, then i enter username and password. After then i am able to access internet. )
Here in screenshot only my pc is visible but another pc is not visible
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the two laptops in the same domain/subnet. check IP addresses of both laptops by `ipconfig /all` command and make sure they can be pinged from each other. also, the network might have file sharing restrictions. check for that.